# Rails seleccionar listado de objeto referenciado en formulario

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Una pregunta de principiante pero he intentado varios opciones y no logro resultado

Tengo un Objeto Cancha que tiene distintas Mmpp, el tema es cuando creo una Cancha debo indicar que Mmpp tiene. Como el campo esta referenciado si pongo 1 funciona y lo guarda, en el show muestra Mmpp:0x00007f7fb1600378 lo cual edito <%= @cancha.mmpp %> y pongo <%= @cancha.mmpp.nombre %>,muestra lo que necesito . El problema es que no se como hacer que en el formulario de Cancha me muestre un listado de los tipos de Mmpp.

```
<%= form.text_field :mmpp_id, class: 'form-control' %>
```

```
create_table "canchas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "nombre"
    t.string "descripcion"
    t.integer "capacidad"
    t.boolean "operativa"
    t.bigint "mmpp_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["mmpp_id"], name: "index_canchas_on_mmpp_id"
```

```
create_table "mmpps", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "nombre"
    t.string "descripcion"
    t.integer "densidad"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

En el formulario del objeto Canchas que esta indexado al objeto Mmpp, para no seleccionar un numero y seleccionar el nombre de la Mmpp finalmente me funciono este codigo

```rb
    <%= form.select :mmpp_id, Mmpp.all.map { |r| [r.nombre, r.id] } %>
```

Comment: Hola Poluxland, me alegra que encontraras una respuesta a tu pregunta. Deberías añadir algo más de información a la respuesta (p.e. ¿qué hace ese código? ¿dónde iría? ¿cómo soluciona el problema?). Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.